# Retrieve multiple records based on multiple AND WHERE conditions

Tags: database, mysql

I am currently struggling with a query that needs to retrieve multiple records from my table based on multiple WHERE clauses. Each WHERE clause contains two conditions.

**Table layout:**

```
+--------------+---------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field        | Type    | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+--------------+---------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id           | int(11) | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| entity_id    | int(11) | YES  | MUL | NULL    |                |
| attribute_id | int(11) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| value        | int(11) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
+--------------+---------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

**What I need to retrieve:**

One or more records matching an array of attribute_id's with corresponding values. In this case, I have an array with the following structure:

```
array(
   attribute => value,
   attribute => value,
   attribute => value
)
```

**The problem:**

I cannot cycle through the array and create WHERE clauses for this query, since each WHERE condition would automatically negate the other. All attribute/value pairs should be matched.

I almost thought I had the solution with this query:

```
SELECT `client_entity_int`. * 
FROM `client_entity_int` 
WHERE (attribute_id IN (1, 3)) 
HAVING (value IN ('0', '3'))
```

... but obviously, this would retrieve both values for both attributes, where I just need attribute 1 to be 0 and attribute 3 to be 3.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This sounds like a UNION of different queries.

```
SELECT ... WHERE ...
UNION
SELECT ... WHERE ...
UNION
SELECT ... WHERE ...
```

Answer (score 3):

If you use an OR, not every WHERE clause will negate the other :)

For example:

```
WHERE (attribute_id = 1 and value = '0')
OR    (attribute_id = 3 and value = '3')
```

To insist that ALL conditions match, count the matches:

```
WHERE    (attribute_id = 1 and value = '0')
OR       (attribute_id = 3 and value = '3')
GROUP BY entity_id 
HAVING   COUNT(*) = 2
```

Comment: Sadly, I need ALL where conditions to be true, so this would not work.

Comment: @Aron Rotteveel: So, just use `AND` instead of `OR`.  Or am I missing something?

Comment: That would not work. When the first clause with attribute_id = 1 returns true, obviously, the second clause with attribute_id = 3 would no longer return true.

Comment: @Aron Rotteveel: You can count the number of matches and check if they equal the total number of conditions (edited in answer.)  Or you can count the matches in client code

Answer (score 1):

would this work?:

```
SELECT `client_entity_int`. * 
FROM `client_entity_int` 
WHERE (attribute_id=1 AND value=0) OR (attribute_id=3 AND value=3)
...
```

Comment: Sadly, I need ALL where conditions to be true, so this would not work.